# Is this tag supposed to say Android?

Tags: support, tags

I came across this tag that I believe should say "Android" not "anroid" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anroid). I am I correct or wrong?

Comment: Probably right; looks like the question(s) with this misspelled tag were fixed. The tag will die soon, provided no one else accidentally uses it.

Comment: Happens a lot, users with high reputation are still human beings and make mistakes. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'm flagging your comment as offensive. ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Oh, you aren't human? All you mammals look alike.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, make your first comment the answer so I can mark it as such. Thanks for the answer. No upvotes from anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem like it was a misspelled tag. It almost certainly has no questions now because someone noticed it, and fixed the spelling (which is the same as changing the tag to the correct one). After a bit of not being used, this tag will disappear.